# Rails Query Table for all records that were created between a certain time of all days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app with PGSQL Database, that allows users to add Posts. 
For analytics purposes, I need to query records that were created between 2 ad 4pm of every day and display that count.

I could get all results and iterate through it, but i do not think that is an efficient way of going about things, cause I am expecting 1000s of records each day.

Comment: Whenever asking for a bit non-standard queries, include the database you are using as these queries tend to become DB-specific

Comment: its PGSql Database, ill edit it and mention it in the post

Comment: Actually, I reread your question and have to agree with @sawa. Are you trying to get the count for each day or one count for all days.

Answer (score 0):

Use PostgreSQL's `EXTRACT` for that. You can refer to more datetime functions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-datetime.html).

Your query should look like:

```
Post.where("EXTRACT(hour FROM created_at) BETWEEN 14 AND 16")
```

add a `.count` if you're interested in the count only.

Please keep timezones in mind, if you're saving datetimes in UTC in database but you're looking for posts between 14-16 in the local timezone, you'll have to shift the hours a bit (or use `AT TIME ZONE` from the link I mentioned to factor in for DST).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :todays_latest_posts, { where("(HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND DATE(created_at) = ?", 14, 16, Date.today) }
end
```

Query records that were created between 2 ad 4pm of every day and display =>

> Post.todays_latest_posts

Sql query will be

```
SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE ((HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 14 AND 16) AND DATE(created_at) = '2018-11-24') LIMIT 11
```

Output =>

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<post id: 112, title: nil, .... created_at: "2018-11-24 11:31:35", updated_at: "2018-11-24 11:31:36">, [], ...]>
```

Count =>

```
Post.todays_latest_posts.count
```